# Why there is a contradiction between verse of brihadaranyaka upanishad?

Tags: upanishads

> 2. Prajapati said to Himself: "Well, let Me make a firm basis for it (semen)." So He created woman. Having created her, He placed her below and worshipped her. Therefore one should worship a woman, placing her below. He (Prajapati) extended His organ that projects and with it impregnated her. (**Verse 6.4.2) brihadaranyaka upanishad Chapter IV—Conception and Birth as Religious Rites** Verse

> He was not at all happy. Therefore people (still) are not happy when alone. He desired a mate. He became as big as man and wife embracing each other. He parted this very body into two. From that came husband and wife. Therefore, said Yājñavalkya, this (body) is one-half of oneself, like one of the two halves of a split pea. Therefore this space is indeed filled by the wife. He was united with her. From that men were born.**(verse1.4.3)Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad Chapter I > Section IV - The Creation and Its Cause**

In the first verse Prajapati created the woman but in the second verse (1.4.3) aham split himself into two man and a woman.

**Why there is a contradiction between these two verses**

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I have made the edits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the first verse Prajapati created the woman but in the second verse (1.4.3) aham split himself into two man and a woman.

They are not contradictory because they can be combined into one coherent event:

First passage:

> He created woman.

Second passage:

> He parted this very body into two. From that came husband and wife.

The first passage says he created a woman. The second passage is explaining *how* he created a woman: by splitting himself into two. So, he created man and woman by splitting himself into two, and then with his male body he impregnated the woman body.

Thus, there is no contradiction between the two passages. Can you find one?

Comment: There is a difference between creating and splitting

Comment: @DarkKnight There is indeed a difference, but they are not logical contradictions. A logical contradiction would be between splitting and non-splitting.

Comment: that's what create means (non splitting).

Comment: @DarkKnight It does not. Create also means "cause". So Prajapati caused man and woman to come into existence by splitting himself.

Comment: OK know I understood it thanks

Comment: i believe it still contradicts other brahma sutras where it says brahman is unchanging but how can it split, second when he had no desire why brahman felt loniness.. i believe the whole statment meant something.. not about brahman at all it trys to convey different message.. like both men and women are created equally.. for creation to progress the male and female concept is necessary.. if it conveys split of brahman than it can contradit lots of sutras

Comment: @PrasannaR Brahman didn't split. *Prajapati* split. Prajapati is some primordial, superhuman sharira of Brahman. Brahman itself is chidachitAtmaka and has no body.

Comment: Prajapati in this context is mostly Brahmaji not the ultimate Brahman. Probably referring to creation of Manu and Shatarupa

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. Both the verses are about Prajapati.

> Hiranya-garbha or Prajapati divided himself into two. Both are his
> elements. The two are not separate and the theory is not one of final
> dualism.
>
> **Commentary on Brihadaranyaka Upanishad I.4.3 by Radhakrishnan.**

The point is that Prajapati creates man and woman by dividing himself.